# linked datepicker com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Tenho um formulário com um período de data ('Data inicio' e 'Data fim'). A data de início não pode ser menor que a data final e a data final não pode ser menor que a data de início. Esses inputs estão utilizando o 'datepicker' do JQuery UI (JQueryUI 1.11.0 e JQuery 3.1.1).

Procurei na documentação do Jquery UI e encontrei o exemplo abaixo:

```
$(function () {
    var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy",
        from = $("#from")
        .datepicker()
        .on("change", function () {
            to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        }),
        to = $("#to").datepicker()
        .on("change", function () {
            from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
        });

    function getDate(element) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
        } catch (error) {
            date = null;
        }

        return date;
    }
});
```

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe muitas outras formas de se fazer isso, por ex:

**utilizando html e jQuery**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#dtaInicio, #dtaFinal").change(function(){
   var inicio = document.getElementById("dtaInicio").value;    var fim = document.getElementById("dtaFinal").value;
    console.log(inicio);
    console.log(fim);
   if (new Date(inicio) > new Date(fim)) {
     alert("inicio maior que fim return false");  
     return false;
   }
  
   
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<label>
Data Inicial:
<input id="dtaInicio" type="date" value="" size=10 />
</label>
<label>
Data Final:
<input id="dtaFinal" type="date" value="" size=10 />
</label>

</html>
```

Experimente colocar uma data inicial maior do que a final, vai retornar false, no exemplo eu coloquei essa verificação na mudança dos inputs, voce pode colocar ao submit de um formulario